# While loop returned nothing at all and removing duplicates of min max

Tags: python

1) upon entering input >> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
the result returned nothing. Must be the while loop i supposed?

2) Also for input such as >> 1 1 1 5 5 7 7 7 7
how do i remove duplicate of 1 and 7? ; meaning duplicate of min and max.
I plan to average the number input by removing duplicate of min and max.
Do i combine max() min() function with list(set(x)) or is there another way round?

New to python here. WHILE permitted only. Do not suggest For

```
even_sum, odd_sum = 0,0
evencount, oddcount = 0,0
count=0
n=0

s = raw_input("Please Input a series of numbers")
numbers = map(int, s.split())

while count<numbers:
     if numbers[n]%2==0:
         evencount = evencount +1# len(numbers)
         even_sum += num
         count=count+1
         n=n+1
else:
        oddcount = oddcount+1#len(numbers)
        odd_sum += num
        count=count+1
        n=n+1

max123 = max(numbers)
min123 = min(numbers)
difference = max123 - min123



print numbers 
numbers.remove(max(numbers))
numbers.remove(min(numbers))

average = sum(numbers)/float(len(numbers))

print "The summation of even and odd numbers are " + str(even_sum) + " and " + str(odd_sum)
print "The difference between biggest and smallest number is " + str(difference)
print "The count of even numbers and odd numbers are " + str(evencount) + " & " + str(oddcount)

print average
```

Comment: Thank you so much! A kiss for you

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
while count<numbers:
```

You are comparing a number to a list. That is valid, but it does not do what you might expect. `count<numbers` is always true, so you are stuck in an infinite loop. Try it:

```
>>> 1000000 < [1, 2]
True
```

What you want to do instead is iterate through all numbers.

```
for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        ...
```

You don't need `count` and you don't need `n` either.

---

Also, the `else:` should be indented, otherwise it will never be executed with this code.

---

**Handicap mode** (without `for`)

```
n = 0
odd_count = 0
odd_sum = 0

while n < len(numbers):
    number = numbers[n]
    if number % 2:
        odd_count += 1
        odd_sum += number
    n += 1

# "even" values can be calculated from odds and totals
```

Comment: I do not wish to use for. Only while is permitted

Comment: That is an important restriction, which should be in the question... Anyway, `while n < len(numbers)` is what you need. And `count` is still not needed.

Comment: I'm sorry! Anyway I have done what you said but the program seems not to be returning anything. Myopia is entering my eyes

Comment: If number[n] issue?

Comment: There, I wrote the whole loop for you. I don't know which part caused you problems ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! Kiss for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#This is modified code i did mark (#error) where your program didn't work 
even_sum, odd_sum = 0,0
evencount, oddcount = 0,0
count=0
n=0

s = raw_input("Please Input a series of numbers")
numbers = map(int, s.split())
print (numbers)

while count<len(numbers): #error thats a list you have to convert that in to int
     if numbers[n]%2==0:
         evencount = evencount +1# len(numbers)
         even_sum += numbers[n] #error index and variable not defined 
         count=count+1
         n=n+1
     else:         #indented error
        oddcount = oddcount+1#len(numbers)
        odd_sum += numbers[n] #error index and variable not defined
        count=count+1
        n=n+1

max123 = max(numbers)
min123 = min(numbers)
difference = max123 - min123

numbers.remove(max(numbers))
numbers.remove(min(numbers))

average = sum(numbers)/float(len(numbers))

print "The summation of even and odd numbers are " + str(even_sum) + " and " + str(odd_sum)


print "The difference between biggest and smallest number is " + str(difference)
print "The count of even numbers and odd numbers are " + str(evencount) + " & " + str(oddcount)
```

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhb kiss for you !!